# Como puedo poner una imagen de fondo en un ImageView sin que se vea borrosa?

Tags: android

Lo que quiero es poner una imagen de fondo en un *ImageView*, pero cuando ejecuto la app esta imagen se ve borrosa y no se porque, también le pongo un ícono de Play y pasa lo mismo se ve borroso. Esto tiene algo que ver con la imagen o existe una manera para mejorar la calidad en la que se muestra la imagen?

Código Java:

Clase Pelicula:

```
private String nombre;
private String sinopsis;
private String genero;
private int duracion;
private int fondo;
private int fondoSecundario;

public Pelicula(String Nombre,String Sinopsis,String Genero,int Duracion,int Fondo,int FondoSecundario)
{
    nombre = Nombre;
    sinopsis = Sinopsis;
    genero = Genero;
    duracion = Duracion;
    fondo = Fondo;
    fondoSecundario = FondoSecundario;
}

protected Pelicula(Parcel in)
{
    nombre = in.readString();
    sinopsis = in.readString();
    genero = in.readString();
    duracion = in.readInt();
    fondo = in.readInt();
    fondoSecundario = in.readInt();
}

 public static final Creator<Pelicula> CREATOR = new Creator<Pelicula>()
{
    @Override
    public Pelicula createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Pelicula(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Pelicula[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Pelicula[size];
    }
};

public String Nombre(){return nombre;}
public String Sinopsis(){return sinopsis;}
public String Genero(){return genero;}
public int Duracion(){return duracion;}
public int Fondo(){return fondo;}
public int FondoSecundario(){return fondoSecundario;}

@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeString(nombre);
    dest.writeString(sinopsis);
    dest.writeString(genero);
    dest.writeInt(duracion);
    dest.writeInt(fondo);
    dest.writeInt(fondoSecundario);
}
```

Así añado un objeto del tipo Pelicula:

```
listaSerie.add(new Serie("The Strain","Sinopsis","Thriller",1,R.drawable.the_strain_fondo,R.drawable.the_strain_fondo1));
```

Clase EntroPelicula:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    pelicula = bundle.getParcelable("Pelicula");

    btnReproducirPelicula = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnReproducir);
    mostrarGeneroPelicula = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrarGeneroPelicula);
    mostrarSinopsisPelicula = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrarSinopsisPelicula);


    mostrarGeneroPelicula.setText("Genero: " + pelicula.Genero());
    mostrarSinopsisPelicula.setText("Sinopsis:" + "\n" + "\n" + pelicula.Sinopsis());
    btnReproducirPelicula.setBackgroundResource(fondoSecundario);

    btnReproducirPelicula.setOnClickListener(this);
```

*pelicula* es un objeto de tipo *Pelicula*.

FondoSecundario() retorna el id de la imagen que está en el Drawable.

Código XML:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#212121"
tools:context="com.example.erick.depelis.EntroPelicula">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnReproducir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mostrarGeneroPelicula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mostrarSinopsisPelicula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tienes que agregar tu código o Layout, por lo que comentas podría ser alguna propiedad que esta haciendo esto a tu imagen.

Comment: Gracias Erick, he agregado una respuesta, trata de cambiar la imagen a una de mayor tamaño y resolución y no deberías tener problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu `ImageView`, el problema parece ser la medida de la imagen, por ejemplo si cargo una imagen de tamaño 200x200 pixeles en el `ImageView` se mostrara correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en cambio si cargo una imagen muy pequeña, por ejemplo de 10x10 pixeles en el `ImageView` se mostraría borrosa ya que al expandirse se pierde la resolucion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar esto, simplemente asegura que la imagen sea de una medida adecuada para que se pueda desplegar en el contenedor de 190dp.

Comment: pero la resolucion de la imagen es 1080 x 1920, y se ve borrosa

Comment: La estas agregando como background, agrega el layout del contenedor

Comment: perdona mi ignorancia pero como hago eso?

Comment: Erick me refiero a tu layout completo :D

Comment: Lo siento pero no supe hacerlo en el código, me podrias decir como porfavor?

Comment: Te referias a agregar el código del layout?, ya que sigo sin poder resolver lo borroso en la imagen

Comment: Ya subí el XML completo de mi layout

Comment: Erick acabo de ver tu xml. En tu codigo no realizas algun manejo de la imagen o cambias alguna propiedad en el ImageView?

Comment: ya agregué todo el Java donde tengo el ImageView, no le he hecho nada, tal cuál está ahí es lo que hice.

Comment: agrega fondoSecundario por favor

Comment: Listo, agregué toda la clase Pelicula donde se encuantra FondoSecundario() y como lleno el objeto con las imagenes.

Comment: Erick podrìas agregar como se ven las imagenes the_strain_fondo y the_strain_fondo1 que se encuentran en el folder /drawable?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43920/discussion-between-elenasys-and-erick-raul-marquez).

Comment: Ya te conteste por el chat

Answer (score 2):

Android cuenta con una variedad extensa de dispositivos, eso crea conflicto con las resoluciones de las imagenes, para evitar esos problemas tenes que crear distintas carpetas, Ej :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Android se encarga de interpretar esos archivos, a la hora de asignar la imagen al view no te dará inconvenientes, seguira siendo "setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lucy_fondo1);"

En la carpeta drawable-hdpi va la imagen original que seria tamaño 100%
en las siguientes carpetas tenes que agregar la misma imagen pero de distintos tamaños te dejo los datos:

```
-drawable-hdpi    -> 100% res: 426dp x 320dp
-drawable-mdpi    -> 150% res: 470dp x 320dp
-drawable-xhdpi   -> 200% res: 640dp x 480dp
-drawable-xxhdpi  -> 300% res: 960dp x 720dp
-drawable-xxxhdpi -> 400% res: resoluciones mayor a 960dp x 720dp
```

aca te dejo la documentación oficial de Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Saludos!